# Вывод фото профиля vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Практикуюсь с ботом вк, и хотелось узнать как вывести главное изображение профиля по id?
Имеется код, который выводит имя и фамилию. Желательно базируясь на нём хотелось бы вывести картинку.

```html
import vk_api

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="") # авторизация через токен (желательно)
vk = vk_api.VkApi(login="", password="") # авторизация через логин и пароль
vk._auth() # Если авторизируетесь через лог и пароль

# получение имени и фамилии

user = vk.method("users.get", {"user_ids": 1}) # вместо 1 подставляете айди нужного юзера
fullname = user[0]['first_name'] +  ' ' + user[0]['last_name']
```

Comment: Как я понимаю нужно работать с параметром fields в users.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вообще на php пишу, но подозреваю, что так:

```
user = vk.method("users.get", {"user_ids": 1, "fields":["photo_max_orig"]})
fullname = user[0]['first_name'] +  ' ' + user[0]['last_name']
imageLink = user[0]['photo_max_orig']
```

[Ссылка на доку](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарен вам!